# Task Scheduler 1.0: What does this error mean

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working with the windows Task Scheduler 1.0 in win32 c++ & I am attempting to create & save a new task. Everything goes fine until I go to save the task by using the following function:

```
IPersistFile :: Save( NULL, TRUE );
```

*The error that is returned is 0x8007052e*

**I have search & searched msdn but I cannot find a defintion for this error. Do you know that the HRESULT error with the value 0x8007052e means?**

Some other info that might be important. I am using Windows 7, using a admin user & attempting to schedule a Daily task/trigger.

Comment: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaperformance/thread/f92816b3-4e6b-4b05-8322-8cbf2d600bd7

Comment: Is the app always return this error code?

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studios Error Lookup tool I find that it means "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. "

In fact, just Googling for that error code returns exactly the same information.

Answer (score 0):

The [HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx) code 0x8007052e is very easy to decode. It consist from three parts

- 8xxxxxxx - means failure (error)
- x007xxxx - means the facility 7
- xxxx052e - meane the error code 0x52e=1326

If you open the `WinError.h` file you will easy find that `FACILITY_WIN32` is 7.

So you have just a standard Win32 error with the code 0x52e=1326. If you search in `WinError.h` for 1326 you will find `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE` with the description

> Logon failure: unknown user name or
>   bad password.